# Confused about BorderRadius

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to make a shopping card layout How can I make grey container rounded from top-right and top left.This what I have done so far .What I am i doing wrong Any help will be appreciated

[Scrrenshot](https://ibb.co/LSy1nQF)

```
Container(
        width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
        height: ScreenUtil().screenHeight,
        color: Colors.black12,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(

              width: 500,
              height: 400,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color:Colors.red,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/x.jpg"),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 300,
              left: 50,
              right: 50,
              child: Container(

                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    topRight:  Radius.circular(20),

                  ),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 130),
                width: 400,

                child: Column(
                  children: [],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Where is the code for calling the "grey container"? The code you've given doesn't have any container with the color grey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to give a height to the second container. Border radius is working fine when you give the container a height.